# VB.net equivalent to Excel Shape - Circle/Ellipse with Beveling and Gradient

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gradient, gdi+, bevelled

[Ellipse Object Created in Excel with Beveling, Gradient, etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STLQJ.png)

Can this be achieved in VB.Net Windows App Form?   Right now I am using:

```
    Dim Disc1 As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
    Disc1.AddEllipse(1, 1, 138, 138)
    Panel1.Region = New Region(Disc1)
```

Any advice that you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can that be done via VB.Net, of course it can.  Maybe displaying images rather than drawing might be a better approach.

Comment: @Hursey   I thought about the "displaying images" approach but I ruled it out since the disc colors, labels, and placement need to be dynamic and user-controlled.    You have give me something to consider.  I could create and customize the images in Excel and then print screen/copy them to Paint and same them as images, for the user to select by color, the overlay the disc images with text labels and then have the app manage the images and labels.  Although that might be extra work, it is an solid option.  Thanks!

Comment: If it was me, I would be going down the road of a user control with an image and a label control.  Add base images for the discs to your project resources, then create new instances of your control and apply the image as appropriate.  Doing this via drawing all possible but seems like a heap of leg work to me

Comment: @Hursey I tend to agree and that is what I am planning to do.  Thanks again!